# C Programming Language 2nd edition exercise 1-12 question

Tags: c

Why the below condition:

```
if (c !=' ' && c !='\t' && c !='\n')
```

matches either:

not space + not \n - when input is "abc \n"

or

not \t + not \n - when input is "abc\t\n"

When AND logical operator is used?
Should not AND require to match all conditions the same time?

Not space + NOT \t + NOT \n

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN   1  /* inside a word */
#define OUT  0  /* outside a word */

int main() {
       int c, state;
       state = OUT;
       while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
           
           if (c !=' ' && c !='\t' && c !='\n')
           
           {
               printf("%c", c);
               state = IN;    
           }
           
           else if (state)
           
           {
               printf("\n");
               state = OUT;
           }
           
       }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not matching/checking(for truth-value) all conditions? Is your program printing `space`, `tab` & `newline`? Note you're printing a `newline` after a word. Use `\v` vertical-tab instead of `\n` in `printf()`

Comment: Well, vertical-tab giving me step-indentations, clearly different from `\n` output.

Comment: when i enter at input text "abc zyx" and hit enter the code prints: abc and xyz in separate lines while there was no tab entered. My understanding is because i check for not space not tab and not new line all three conditions must be met to go to else if.

Comment: But if i type: abc xyz with tab in between it also works although there was no space.

Comment: What? Can a character be a `newline`, `tab` & a `space` at the same time? It can be only one of them at any given time. We're checking for, not a space, not a newline & not a tab. So all the characters pass this test except `newline`, `tab` & `space`.

Comment: Are you familiar with [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)? Try applying them to the condition in question.

Comment: thx for the hint. I got trapped in wrong thinking and finally saw my own incorrect logic.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused regarding what the condition is actually checking for.

This condition:

```
if (c !=' ' && c !='\t' && c !='\n')
```

Written out as English, says: "if `c` is not a space AND `c` is not a tab AND `c` is not a newline".

In other words, the condition is true when `c` matches *none* of those 3 characters.

Comment: Sorry just realized i asked my question incorrectly.
I edited it.

Comment: @bwspot The answer stands.  All three conditions must be satisfied.  Why do you think that's not the case?

Comment: when i enter at input text "abc zyx" and hit enter the code prints: abc and xyz in separate lines while there was no tab entered.

Comment: @bwspot Yes, that makes sense.  The condition is true when any letter is encountered and false when it sees either a space, tab, or newline.  After reading the characters 'a', 'b', and 'c', a space is read so the condition is false and the "else" portion is entered which prints a newline since `state` was true.

Comment: You said "when it sees either a space, tab, or newline" but is not AND meaning it must much all three?  Would not OR be more like either?

Comment: @bwspot The condition is true if `c` is not a space AND `c` is not a tab AND `c` is not a newline.  That means the condition is false if it **is** any one of those three.

Comment: Yes i finally figured out my wrong thinking. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It is working as intended, test it with vertical-tab.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN   1  /* inside a word */
#define OUT  0  /* outside a word */

int main() {
    int c, state;
    state = OUT;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
            printf ("%c", c);
            state = IN;
        } else if (state) {
            printf ("\v");
            state = OUT;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`space`, `newline` & `tab` chars are ignored and after every word we print a `vertical-tab`. We see this step pattern to prove that.

There are `tab`s in `2nd          edition`

```
./a.out 
C Programming Language 2nd          edition exercise 1-12 question
C
 Programming
            Language
                    2nd
                       edition
                              exercise
                                      1-12
                                          question
```

Comment: I am not saying it is not working.  I just want to understand why AND does not need to match all conditions at the same time.

Comment: You're thinking `if (c ==' ' && c =='\t' && c =='\n')`. Which will never be true for any character.

Comment: I think i got trapped in some stupid logic.  Finally I get it.  So if the input is for example "A " and i press enter which translates to "A" "space" "\n" , then when A is processed it means it is not space not tab and not new line at the time so all 3 conditions are met, then when space is processed then the condition is not met and moves to if else.

Comment: I think i will delete this question so i dont confuse others with my stupidity.

Comment: If you delete it, then you think our time has no value.

Comment: Thank you all for guiding me in the right direction.